# Is is possible to index data into Elastic Search without using Logstash or FileBeats or Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, filebeat

Elastic Search is new to me. I want to know whether it is possible to index data into Elastic Search with ES framework alone? (without using its stack members like Logstash, FileBeats, Kibana, etc)

Answer (score 0):

You can use curl commands in your terminal. Some famous ones

For delete an index

```html
curl -X DELETE 'http://localhost:9200/samples'
```

For listing all indexes

```html
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'
```

For adding a document to an index

```html
curl -XPUT --header 'Content-Type: application/json' http://localhost:9200/samples/_doc/1 -d '{
   "school" : "Harvard"         
}'
```

For bulk load data in JSON format

```html
export pwd="elastic:"

curl --user $pwd  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-ndjson' -XPOST 'https://58571402f5464923883e7be42a037917.eu-central-1.aws.cloud.es.io:9243/0/_bulk?pretty' --data-binary @<file>
```

For showing the cluster health

```html
curl --user $pwd  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XGET https://58571402f5464923883e7be42a037917.eu-central-1.aws.cloud.es.io:9243/_cluster/health?pretty
```

For query and returning some desired fields

```html
GET filebeat-7.6.2-2020.05.05-000001/_search
 {
    "_source": ["suricata.eve.timestamp","source.geo.region_name","event.created"],
    "query":      {
        "match" : { "source.geo.country_iso_code": "GR" }
    }
}
```

You can find more on [Here](https://www.bmc.com/blogs/elasticsearch-commands/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Big time.

There are a ton of tools you can use and a stack of SDKs, or you roll your own producer to hit the indexing APIs.

Here's a few examples:

- [Python Elasticsearch SDK](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/)
- [Official Elasticsearch Ruby SDK](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby)
- [Official Elasticsearch Golang SDK](https://github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch)
- [Fluentd's Elasticsearch output](https://docs.fluentd.org/output/elasticsearch)
- [Kafka Elasticsearch Connector](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-elasticsearch-connector-tutorial/)
- [Native `Index APIs`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices.html)

Elastic publishes lists of [officially supported clients](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/index.html) and [community supported clients](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/community/current/index.html), but they're heavy on programming languages and don't include things like the Fluentd output, the Kafka connector, and so on.